# Hide MAAttachedWindow when clicking outside

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, event-handling, nswindow, show-hide

I'm using an [MAAttachedWindow](http://mattgemmell.com/2007/10/03/maattachedwindow-nswindow-subclass) to display a custom window under a NSStatusItem in the Menubar.
Everything works fine, but I can't find an easy way to hide it when the user clicks outside of the window. I want to implement this behavior because it's what the user expects.

This is the code used to display the `MAAttachedWindow`:

```
- (void)toggleAttachedWindowAtPoint:(NSPoint)pt {
    if (!self.attachedWindow) {  
        self.attachedWindow = [[MAAttachedWindow alloc] initWithView:logView
              attachedToPoint:pt 
               inWindow:nil 
                 onSide:MAPositionBottom 
                atDistance:5.0];

  [self.attachedWindow setLevel:kCGMaximumWindowLevel];
 }

 if(isVisible)
  [self.attachedWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
 else
  [self.attachedWindow orderOut];
}
```

This code gets triggered by an `NSStatusItem` with a custom view which intercepts a click on it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be able to do this via the window's delegate method:

`- (void)windowDidResignKey:(NSNotification *)notification`

Set yourself as the window's delegate, and implement that to call through to your toggle method.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know this method exists.

Answer (score 1):

This is based on **Carter Allen** answer, but maybe will be helpfull to someone as i lost couple of hours trying to figure out the reason behind an `EXEC_BAD_ACCESS`, in short you can't `release` the `attachedWindow` inside his `windowDidResignKey` notification, so use `autorelease`:

```
- (void)windowDidResignKey:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    NSLog(@"MainWinDelegate::windowDidResignKey: %@", [aNotification object]);

    if (fAttachedWindow && [aNotification object] == fAttachedWindow) {
        [window removeChildWindow:fAttachedWindow];
        [fAttachedWindow orderOut:self];
        [fAttachedWindow autorelease];
        fAttachedWindow = nil;
    }
}
```