# Getting MAAttachedWindow (Really a view) to close when clicked outside of

Tags: cocoa, view, window

I have a `MAAttachedWindow` that shows itself when a status bar item is clicked. I need to have it close when its clicked outside of. I found some other [directions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696689/hide-maattachedwindow-when-clicking-outside) that say to set it as a delegate and use `- (void)windowDidResignKey:(NSNotification *)notification` to detect when the user exits the window. I've tried it many times but can't seem to get it working which is probably because I didn't correctly set the delegate. Whats the best way to set the delegate so it will respond to the notification? The code is available [here](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/03/04/using-maattachedwindow-with-an-nsstatusitem).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out to get the notification you have to register for it.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(windowDidResignKey:) 
                                                 name:NSWindowDidResignKeyNotification 
                                               object:self];
```