# Dismiss Custom Window for NSStatusItem

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindow, nsstatusitem

I've got a custom window popping up when an NSStatusItem is clicked. The code is based on [MAAtachedwindow](http://mattgemmell.com/source#maattachedwindow). Everything is working great but I can't figure out a way to dismiss the window when the user clicks on something else like another status bar item, or another app.

Here's my code for creating the window:

```
    statusItem = [[[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] statusItemWithLength:width] retain];

    //setup custom status menu view
    CGFloat height = [[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] thickness];
    NSRect viewFrame = NSMakeRect(0.0f, 0.0f, width, height);
    statusMenuView = [[[_ISStatusMenuView alloc] initWithFrame:viewFrame] retain];
    statusMenuView.offset = aOffset;
    statusItem.view = statusMenuView;

    //setup the window to show when clicked
    NSRect contentRect = NSZeroRect;
    contentRect.size = aView.frame.size;
    statusMenuWindow = [[[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:contentRect
                                   styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask
                                     backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered 
                                       defer:NO] retain];

    [statusMenuWindow setLevel:NSPopUpMenuWindowLevel];
    [statusMenuWindow setBackgroundColor:[NSColor clearColor]];
    [statusMenuWindow setMovableByWindowBackground:NO];
    [statusMenuWindow setExcludedFromWindowsMenu:YES];
    [statusMenuWindow setOpaque:NO];
    [statusMenuWindow setHasShadow:NO];
    [statusMenuWindow useOptimizedDrawing:YES];
    [[statusMenuWindow contentView] addSubview:aView];
    [statusMenuWindow setDelegate:self];

    statusMenuView.statusMenuWindow = statusMenuWindow;
```

And here is how I'm showing the window:

```
- (void)centerView{
    NSRect menuFrame = self.window.frame;
    NSRect windowFrame = self.statusMenuWindow.frame;
    NSPoint menuPoint = NSMakePoint(NSMidX(menuFrame), NSMinY(menuFrame));
    menuPoint.x -= windowFrame.size.width*0.5f;
    menuPoint.y -= windowFrame.size.height+self.offset;
    [self.statusMenuWindow setFrameOrigin:menuPoint];
    [self.statusMenuWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
}
```

I was hoping the `windowDidResignKey` delegate method would do the trick but it doesn't go off with this configuration. The delegate is working because `windowDidMove` does run.

```
- (void)windowDidResignKey:(NSNotification *)notification{
    NSLog(@"windowDidResignKey");
    [statusMenuView hideView];
}

- (void)windowDidResignMain:(NSNotification *)notification{
    NSLog(@"windowDidResignMain");
}

- (void)windowDidMove:(NSNotification *)notification{
    NSLog(@"windowDidMove");
}
```

So to recap, how can I hide my custom window when the user clicks on anything else, the way the standard status bar menus work?

*Edit*
After looking at the [Popup](http://blog.shpakovski.com/2011/07/cocoa-popup-window-in-status-bar.html) example the only thing I was missing was I had to subclass NSPanel and make it so it  could become the key window.

```
@interface Panel : NSPanel
@end

@implementation Panel

- (BOOL)canBecomeKeyWindow{
    return YES;
}

@end
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hide MAAttachedWindow when clicking outside](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696689/hide-maattachedwindow-when-clicking-outside)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make sure your window can become the key window, and call your window's orderOut: method when it resigns key. You should be using a custom NSWindowController, if you are not already, in which case you would just call its "close" method to dismiss your window.

Instead of posting a bunch of code, I would suggest you just look at this excellent, recently-posted example of attaching a window to a status item:
[Shpakovski Popup Window Example](http://blog.shpakovski.com/2011/07/cocoa-popup-window-in-status-bar.html)